# using javascript or iframe to sync two buttons

Tags: javascript, button, iframe, synchronization

I have two buttons on an html page, button A and button B.

On first loading the page, both buttons have an 'image', image-1.

When I click on button A, the image changes to image-2, but button B stays the same (image-1).  When I click on button B, the image changes to images-2, but button A stays the same (image-1).

I would like it so that if you click on 'either button' (A or B), the button images for BOTH change to image-2.

I currently have both buttons in 'iframe', so the buttons are decoupled.

Can you please recommend a javascript to do this? (or, is there a way to 'sync' the iframe buttons on a single page?)

Comment: post some code and explain why you're using iframes. generally speaking, it's just a matter of selecting the elements of the page that you want to change (for example, by the element ID) and applying the changes (which apparently you already know how to do).

Comment: Here's the code.
iframe in code:
<iframe src="boost1.php?$url">
--
(boost1.php)
<?php
$pageURL = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$fulluri = explode("?",$pageURL);
$boosturl = $fulluri[1];
echo "
<form action=boost2.php method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
<input  name=boosturl type=hidden value=$boosturl>
<input type=\"image\" src=\"IconFirst.png\" />
</form>
";
?>
--
(boost2.php):
<?php
$boosturl = trim($_POST['boosturl']);
//data updating
echo "
<img src=\"IconSecond.png\" />
";
?>

Comment: I need to convert it to javascript, because I have the iframe 2 places on the same page.  So, when I click on one iframe button, it changes to the 2nd button.  But the 2nd iframe button doesn't I want both to change, in addition to executing the php function.  I think I can best do this in javascript, but need help with this if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little example to show you how to sync two buttons using JavaScript.  Let me know if you need some explanation . . .

```js
function sync1(){
  
  var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
  var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
  
  button1.style.background = 'red';
  button1.style.color = 'white';
  
  button2.style.background = 'red';
  button2.style.color = 'white';
  
}

function sync2(){
  
  var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
  var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
  
  button1.style.background = 'blue';
  button1.style.color = 'white';
  
  button2.style.background = 'blue';
  button2.style.color = 'white';
  
}
```

```html
<button class="1" onclick="sync1()" id="button1">I can change the other button!</button>
<br /><br />
<button class="1" onclick="sync2()" id="button2">Me too!</button>
```

Comment: This helps a lot, and there's more that we want to do here (if you have any thoughts or suggestions).  

We need either button to launch a php script, and as the script gets launched, 'both' buttons change color.

Also, we have 'img src' for each of the buttons. So, for both buttons they have one image, and if clicked on, both buttons turn to another image.

Anyway, any help you can give is appreciated!  Thanks.